# If I shred /dev/sda, do I delete partitions?

Tags: partition, partition-table, shred

If I am wiping my `/dev/sda` harddrive, do I need to first repartition it (for example, with GParted), or will `shred /dev/sda` wipe the partition table too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, wiping `/dev/sda` wipes the partition table too. It also wipes any area of the drive unallocated to any partition.

Although the kernel will typically keep partition tables in memory. `partprobe` can be used to tell the kernel to update them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because /dev/sda is the whole disk, which also contains your boot sector, which contains the partition table. Take a look at [this](http://www.linfo.org/partition_table.html).